# One switch port suddenly no longer at gigabit speed

Tags: switch, gigabit-ethernet

I've got this manageable switch : [https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Ethernet-Sheilded-Replacement-TL-SG108E/dp/B00K4DS5KU/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K4DS5KU)
in my network for about 3 months now.

Yesterday I noticed that a computer directly connected to it did not have gigabit link (100mbps instead). Since I had just reinstalled it I though it was related but after swapping the cables between different ports and devices, I came to the conclusion that the issue was the switch itself.

I've also checked that all the ports are on 'auto' setting.

What do you think of it? Should I buy a new one and return this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a gigabit connection needs all 4 pairs, check first that all the 8 pins are able to have contact: any of them shouldn't be contorted and there should be no dirt. During the testing you could force the port to operate as gigabit instead of auto.

Comment: I already tried to force gigabit speed but then the port status show "disconnected" or something. I'm going to try what you say.

Comment: It works now. Apparently the cable was not properly connected, I had to force a little.

Comment: A physical problem, just like I assumed. :)

Answer (score 0):

> What do you think of it? Should I buy a new one and return this one?

I think it is a cheap consumer switch that has no place in a professional environment. It's up to you what you do with it.

Comment: Well I'm not a professional, I think I shouldn't have posted here. Anyway you think it's not fixable?

Comment: Yes, [su] is a better place.